# How to Add Custom post Thumbnails in WordPress Theme without Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, custom-wordpress-pages

On my WordPress website, I have a blog page that contains 4 posts, and each post has an image of size 1080x900 px. I want to show this image as a thumbnail of 350x300px on the WordPress site.

How can I add custom thumbnail size in the function.php file and what is the next step to do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 350, 300, true );
```

Images will be available as a thumb in that size after you [regenerate media](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/).

For more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: If possible can you tell me the complete process from the first step to the last step, because I got confused after reading different articles and blogs?